# Hibernate asm ,cglib Maven dependency with spring relase 3.1.2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

Can some one please list all the maven dependency that are needed for me to have a compile and runtime success for a spring-hibernate web project which uses @Autowired annotations.

I have tried so many combinations but to no avail. Once I put the compile EAR file in WebSphere liberty profile, it fails with `NoSuchMethod . registerStatic call which goes to Enhancer  class in cglib.`

I tried several different combinations of cglib cglib-nodep asm spring-hibernate for almost 3 days now but I get different errors at runtime.
Can some one please list the correct maven dependencies needed.

I use hibernate3 in  my jars and the project is an old spring project that I can not use the latest releases .

```
[ERROR   ] Context initialization failed
Error creating bean with name 'backgroundEditController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.service.BackgroundService com.controller.BackgroundEditController.backgroundServ; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] for bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'backgroundEditController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.service.BackgroundService com.controller.BackgroundEditController.backgroundServ; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] for bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2389)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] for bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1262)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:833)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.findClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:118)
    at [internal classes]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
    ... 25 more

[ERROR   ] SRVE8052E: Logging ClassNotFoundException
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
[ERROR   ] SRVE0276E: Error while initializing Servlet [app]: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0200E: Servlet [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]: Could not find required class - org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper$1.run(ServletWrapper.java:1573)
    at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] SRVE0321E: The [springSecurityFilterChain] filter did not load during start up.
Filter [springSecurityFilterChain]: could not be initialized
```

other combinations I get different errors.

```
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:346)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:222)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2389)
at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/asm/util/TraceClassVisitor
at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.toByteArray(DebuggingClassWriter.java:73)
at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:26)
at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.
Hibernate needs to have the cglib excluded in the maven pom file.
Here is how you should have it. Also there are also different version of the joda-time-hibernate that download cglib and you need to exclude that out as well.. asm and cglib mismatch was the cause of the issue.

```
om.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2389)
at [internal classes]
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/asm/util/TraceClassVisitor

```
<dependency>
<groupId>cglib</groupId>
<artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
<version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
  <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
<version>3.5.6-Final</version>
<exclusions>
  <exclusion>
         <groupId>cglib</groupId>
         <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
  <exclusion>
         <groupId>asm</groupId>
         <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
         <groupId>asm</groupId>
         <artifactId>asm-attr</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>joda-time</groupId>
<artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>joda-time</groupId>
<artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
    <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
          <groupId>cglib</groupId>
          <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
       <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
     <dependency>
  <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
  <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
          <groupId>cglib</groupId>
          <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
</exclusions>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```